# Autofocus won't apply to input box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to autofocus this input box, that's appears when 'Get Started' is pressed:

```
<input name="hex" type="search" autofocus="autofocus">
```

However, after applying autofocus="autofocus"> in the input this doesn't apply.

I have also tried to give the input an ID and used jQuery:

```
$('input').focus();
```

but again, this does't seem to apply, can anybody help?

[Live example](http://hexactly.co.uk/test/)

Comment: JSfiddle please. Although I though you could just do `<input autofocus>`

Comment: Autofocus only applies when the page loads. Both of your examples work for me BTW.

Comment: Try adding `tabindex="-1"` to the input element

Comment: @enyce12 This doesn't seem to apply either

Comment: How do you slide in the overlay? Show us some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that it is focusing though when you click the button it unfocuses so when the overlay comes down when it is on it is no longer focused.

The way to get round this is to add:

```
$('input').focus();
```

When you do the animation of the overlay coming down on button click

Change the contents of demo1.js to this:

```
(function() {
    var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
            $('input').focus();
        }
    }
    triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

Comment: Probably he's sliding down the overlay with `$(..).slideDown()`. So he could just add a callback: `$(..).slideDown(500, function(){ $('input').focus(); })`

Comment: @enyce12 I have no idea where I Should be applying this, sorry for the bother. The scripts running the overlay are cassie.js and demo1.js. Should the code you suggested be applied in there?

Comment: @thesarahjay have edited above answer and now should work if you follow what I say

Comment: @Hive7 Hi, thanks for the suggestion. This somehow doesn't work either when I apply your answer :/

Comment: Are you sure I applied to the js on yr site and it worked @thesarahjay

Comment: @Hive7 Yes, I updated the live if you want to have a look, demo1 has been updated [Live example](http://hexactly.co.uk/test/)

Comment: The block of code below that is what I meant @thesarahjay

Comment: Sorry it's my damn cache, apologies. It works. Thanks so much. @Hive7

Comment: thats ok @thesarahjay